# Finding the values in a dictionary which are closest to a given number

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

New to python 3 and trying to play about with some dictionaries.

What I'm going for is I have a dictionary with a lot of keys e.g. `{Dog : 2, Cat : 5, Fish : 3}` but its really big. Now I'm given a value e.g. `2` and I want it to return ten dictionary elements have have the value closest to `2`.

Any ideas if it is possible to do this, and if so can some one point me on the right path?

Sorry I have just realised that actually all I want to be returned is the key.

Comment: Closest as in 2 and 3 or some more scientific approach like [nearest neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html)

Comment: Is the value always a number?

Comment: so if in my dictionary there were `5` elements with value `2`, `1` element with value `3`, `4` with value `1`, `6` with value `0`, `9` with value `4`. Then it would return the elements with values `2`,`1` and `3`. The value is always a number in this dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  With Python, use [heapq.nsmallest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)

```
import heapq
d = <iterable of many key-value pairs>

def f(pair): return abs(pair[1]-2)

least10 = heapq(10, d, key=f)
```

For more general answers, search web for 'n smallest'.  There are related answers already on SO.

Comment: I always like it when I see a core-dev come around and answer. :-) This is better than iterating but it might not be as intuitive for the OP (As a beginner).